# How should I select a Windows Server AMI image for use with the AWS free tier as a WAMP stack?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008, wamp, amazon-ami

I recently realized that Amazon's AWS free tier allows you to use both a micro Linux *and* a micro Windows server free for one year. I've only been running Linux instances so far, but I'm curious to give the Windows server a try since it's free.

Ubuntu has a [sweet cloud portal](https://ubuntu.com/blog) which shows you what AMI images they have available for use with EC2, but I haven't found anything like that for Windows.

I realize that the launch instance wizard gives you a few options:

[image: Picture.png]

But I dont' see any pre-built WAMP stacks. Also, [bitnami has a WAMP stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp) but I can't seem to find an AMI image for it.

Is launching a Windows instance similar to Linux? I'm assuming I can find a reputable WAMP AMI somewhere where, put the AMI number into the launch console, and then RDP to the box. So, if that's the case, how can I find a reputable WAMP stack AMI to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, yes. Launching a Windows AMI is exactly like launching a Linux one. Except for the fact that you RDP, and not SSH to the instance, and you have to wait a couple of minutes to connect to your instance, in order for the Admin password to be generated.

For your second question, I would recommend you to start at the [Bitnami site](http://bitnami.org/stack/lampstack), but I saw that they are only providing LAMP instances as of today. I don't know what is your concept of reputable, but I found out two public AMIs (from Bitnami as well, but a little older, as it seems) that might help you. Just launch (on your EC2 Management Console) the `Classic Wizard`, `Community AMIs`, and search for `WAMP` and you will find them out.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow - only two images when searching for WAMP in the community AMI's!? I've picked the newer one and launched it. This is a little off topic but how do you know what the admin password is? I'm used to using SSH keys.

Comment: Right-click your instance (in the `My Instances` view) and click `Get Windows Password`.

Comment: perfect - thanks so much! ps: if anyone else has notes about where to find WAMP ami's I will gladly upvote your answers